# Mips outputing too many strings

Tags: assembly, mips

I am having errors with this program, more details at bottom. Anything you notice i am doing wrong please let me know as well.

#### CMPEN 331, Homework 3

```
# switch to the Text segment
.text

# the program is defined here
.globl main

main:
li $v0, 4  #introduction
la $a0, HW
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, Name
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, intro
syscall
li $v0, 4
la $a0, question
syscall     #end introduction   

li $v0, 8   #input 10 characters
li $a1, 10
move $t3, $a0
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall

GetLength:
lb $t0,($t3)
add $t3, $t3, 1
bne $t0, $zero, GetLength
sub $t3, $t3, 1
li $v0, 11

Loop:
sub     $t3, $t3, 1     # something around here isnt working
la      $t0, ($t3)   
lb      $a0, ($t0)   #getting an error here
syscall
ble     $t3, $t0  Loop   

li $v0, 10  # ends program
syscall

##########

.data
# global data is defined here
HW:
.asciiz "CMPEN 331 Homework 3\n"
Name:
.asciiz "Cullen Wilcox\n \n\n"
intro: .asciiz "Lets see if your word is a Palidrome!\n"
question: .asciiz "Please enter a word that is ten letters or less: "
newline: "\n\n "
```

So Where i Put (error here) is my issue, (thats where mars is telling me i have an error.)  It is outputting what i want correctly, but it is also outputting every string backwards in reverse. like the first line of output is CMPEN 331 homework 3, the last line of output ends up being 3 krowemoh 133 NEPMC..... im not sure why this is happening , but i believe it is inside of the Loop part of my program.

This program takes an input from the user and outputs what they entered in reverse. (also the program never ends. (never says this program has finished running.) takes about 2-3 minutes for MARS to unlock because i believe it is infinitely looping. re-asked, wasnt getting a response

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mips output not working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962059/mips-output-not-working-correctly)

Comment: _"re-asked, wasnt getting a response"_. Re-asking the same question is not allowed. You'll just have to wait and hope that someone eventually answers your original question. You might be able to improve the likelihood of getting an answer by editing the question to more clearly define the problem.